# How to automatic capture screenshot using selenium ide

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I want to take automatic screen shot of each page visited, I want to do it using selenium ide, I have tried with CAPTUREENTIREPAGESCREENSHOT but this is manual, i want automated.

Answer (score 1):

The Selenium IDE for Firefox has no feature which capture screenshots automatically while browsing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `captureEntirePageScreenshot` command and appropriate path location following the command.

For your reference:

https://seleniumonlinetrainingexpert.wordpress.com/2012/11/29/how-to-capturing-screenshots-from-selenium-ide/

Comment: Thank your for reply But I need to capture screenshot automatically, I don't want to use captureEntirePageScreenshot. when button is click it will capture the screenshot automatically.